# Aggregating Data using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot the data using R by reading my CSV file which contains some values which were logged on per-second basis. I would like R to aggregate the data to per-minute basis so that I can plot the per-minute data using `plot(TIME,VALUE.)`.
My CSV file contains something like this;

```
Store No.,Date,Time,Watt
33,2011/09/26,09:11:01,0.0599E+03
34,2011/09/26,09:11:02,0.0597E+03
35,2011/09/26,09:11:03,0.0598E+03
36,2011/09/26,09:11:04,0.0596E+03
37,2011/09/26,09:11:05,0.0593E+03
38,2011/09/26,09:11:06,0.0595E+03
39,2011/09/26,09:11:07,0.0595E+03
40,2011/09/26,09:11:08,0.0595E+03
41,2011/09/26,09:11:09,0.0591E+03
```

I'm having trouble aggregating the Time and Watt column on per-minute basis as I'm a newbie to R. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Search r-help and/or StackOverflow for answers involving the zoo package and aggregation.  This has been addressed a hundred times.  Or just install zoo and read its four vignettes, maybe starting with the updated version of the published paper.

Comment: Actually i tried searching StackOverflow but couldn't find a similar question addressing the time column w.r.t. the second column. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming Store No. is irrelevant and changing the last three rows in the example data shown in the question to be `09:12:..` rather than `09:11:..` so we have at least two different minutes:

```
# create test data

Lines <- "Store No.,Date,Time,Watt
33,2011/09/26,09:11:01,0.0599E+03
34,2011/09/26,09:11:02,0.0597E+03
35,2011/09/26,09:11:03,0.0598E+03
36,2011/09/26,09:11:04,0.0596E+03
37,2011/09/26,09:11:05,0.0593E+03
38,2011/09/26,09:11:06,0.0595E+03
39,2011/09/26,09:12:07,0.0595E+03
40,2011/09/26,09:12:08,0.0595E+03
41,2011/09/26,09:12:09,0.0591E+03"
cat(Lines, "\n", file = "data.txt")

# read in aggregating at the same time

library(zoo)
library(chron)
z <- read.zoo("data.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",", index = 2:3,
    FUN = paste, FUN2 = function(x) trunc(as.chron(x), "00:01:00"), 
    aggregate = mean)[, -1]
```

Here `FUN` is applied to the columns specified by `index`.  It pastes them together and then `FUN2` is applied to the result of `FUN` creating a `chron` date/time.  Finally rows with the same values of `FUN2` are then aggregated taking the mean of `Watt` giving:

```
> z
(09/26/11 09:11:00) (09/26/11 09:12:00) 
           59.63333            59.36667
```

Depending on what is wanted the `aggregate` argument could be changed to `aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1)` in place of the `aggregate` argument shown.

For more info and examples, load the zoo package and look in `?read.zoo`, `?aggregate.zoo` and `vignette("zoo-read")` as well as the other vignettes and help files.

UPDATE: Slight simplification by using the `FUN2` argument.  Not sure but that `read.zoo` argument
may not have existed at the time this question was first answered.